# Java: How to check if an "Array of Arrays" is empty/null?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `Array of Arrays`. I would like to ckeck if "**All elemnets are null**".

Here is how I am creating the `Array of Arrays`:

```
double[][] arr = new double[extrasSize][]
```

(*The size of the array depends on an Android bundle that I am passing from one activity to another*)

Obviously, I cannot use `(arr.length == 0)`.

Then again, if I have to use `(arr == null)` then I need to go through each and every single element in the Array. This might be the simplest solution but definitely not the smartest one. Especially, if the number of these elemnets is huge and not fixed.

Is there is another way to check if an `Array of Arrays` is empty/null  ?

Comment: "This might be the simplest solution but definitely not the smartest one" - why not the smartest one? Each array entry might be null, empty or not empty. You have to inspect each one.

Comment: You are using primitives (double, lower case D). A primitive value can never be null. Are you asking how to check if the nested array is null?

Comment: If your array has empty arrays in it, you will have to iterate over every array and check that they are empty. You can't escape that.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken the value might not be null, but one of the inner arrays or the outer one might be ``null``. For instance ``arr[0]==null`` might be ``true``.

Comment: Is there any way to check all array elemets in definitly same time? without looking each elements seperately? I thought that, do whatevery you want, on binary world, that will check all array elements one by one in your memory. Am i wrong?

Comment: @f1sh that's exactly what I pointed out ;)

Comment: Take a step back. Why would you want to *explicitly* check the "all null" condition? If you can handle some nulls, where is the problem with *all nulls*?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking for:

```
double[][] arr = new double[extrasSize][]
```

Creates an empty array, holding `extrasSize` slots that each holds a `double[]`. Those slots are null upon creation.

If you want to check later on; there is no other way but iterating over the entries and see if they are null:

```
for (int i=; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == null) { ...
```

And just for the record: the arr slots point to double[] Objects; so they are **null** initially. When you create such a double[] array, the slots are double numbers, and will all be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check as:

```
boolean isAllNull =Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(singleArray -> singleArray == null);
```

This simple code will return `true` you if all single dimensional arrays are `null` (inside your two-dimensional array).